# How do I invert grep matches followed by some xml body in logs

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to grep out ( invert grep / reverse grep ) some xml data from my log files. grep -v works , but i have some giant xml body that gets printed every 5 minutes in my logs and I want to grep that whole xml body out, because it is mostly noise and makes it harder for me to parse the log file. The lines i want to grep out looks something like this.

```
date time pattern
<xml-tag>
   <smaller tag1>
   <smaller tag2>
   </smaller tag1>
   </smaller tag2>
 </xml-tag>
```

When I try something like

```
grep -v "pattern" log-file
```

the pattern gets grepped out . But the xml gets left behind. Anyway to grep out all contents starting from   to all contents ending in  ? I also tried

```
egrep -v -A6 "pattern" log-file
```

as a last ditch effort . I assuming this should grep out 6 lines after the match. That didn't work either for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

To skip all lines between pattern and the closing xml tag:

```
awk '/pattern/,/<\/xml-tag>/ {next} 1' logfile
```

With this as the logfile:

```
$ cat logfile
before1
date time pattern
<xml-tag>
   <smaller tag1>
   <smaller tag2>
   </smaller tag1>
   </smaller tag2>
 </xml-tag>
after1
```

The output produced is:

```
$ awk '/pattern/,/<\/xml-tag>/ {next} 1' logfile
before1
after1
```

#### How it works

In `awk`, the expression `/pattern/,/<\/xml-tag>/` defines a range of lines that starts with a line that has `pattern` in it and ends with the next line that has `<\/xml-tag>` in it.  For any such line, the commend `next` is executed, meaning that the line is not printed and `awk` starts processing the next line.  If `next` is not executed, in other words we are not in the unwanted block, then the `1` is executed which, in `awk`, is short-form for "print this line".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` that not use the range function:

```
awk '/pattern/ {f=1} !f; /<\/xml-tag>/ {f=0}' file
before1
after1
```

Range function is nice, but less flexible if other test are to be done.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/pattern/,/<\/xml-tag>/d' logfile
```